# how to remove an array element in it's current position and put it at the end?

Tags: php

let's say I have this array

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [total] => 17
    [count] => 0
    [start] => 0
    [result] => Array
        (
            [Business Services] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 171
                            [subcat] => 12345
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 22
                            [subcat] => Business Opportunities
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 23
                            [subcat] => Courier Services
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 24
                            [subcat] => Databases
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 25
                            [subcat] => Office Furniture & Equipment
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 26
                            [subcat] => Other Business Services
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 27
                            [subcat] => Printing & Copying
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 28
                            [subcat] => Publications
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 29
                            [subcat] => Security Products & Services
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 3
                            [subcatid] => 30
                            [subcat] => Translation Services
                            [maincat] => Business Services
                        )

                )

            [Courses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 45
                            [subcat] => Academic Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 46
                            [subcat] => Computer Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 47
                            [subcat] => Cooking & Baking Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 48
                            [subcat] => Dance Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 49
                            [subcat] => Fitness & Gym Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 50
                            [subcat] => Flower Arrangement Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 51
                            [subcat] => Hair Dressing & Beauty Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 52
                            [subcat] => Language Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 53
                            [subcat] => Music Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 60
                            [subcat] => Others
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 54
                            [subcat] => Photography & Video Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 55
                            [subcat] => Self Improvement Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 56
                            [subcat] => Swimming Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 57
                            [subcat] => Tuition
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 58
                            [subcat] => Yoga & Pilates Lessons
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 6
                            [subcatid] => 59
                            [subcat] => Youth Programs & Courses
                            [maincat] => Courses
                        )

                )

            [Hobbies & Interests] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 88
                            [subcat] => Action Figures & Collectibles
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 89
                            [subcat] => Antiques & Collectibles
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 91
                            [subcat] => Books & Magazines
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 92
                            [subcat] => Building Toys
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 94
                            [subcat] => Club Memberships
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 95
                            [subcat] => Comics & Manga
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 96
                            [subcat] => Computer & Console Games
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 97
                            [subcat] => Florist
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 98
                            [subcat] => Gift Ideas
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 99
                            [subcat] => Musical Instruments
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 104
                            [subcat] => Others
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [maincatid] => 11
                            [subcatid] => 101
                            [subcat] => RC (Remote Control)
                            [maincat] => Hobbies & Interests
                        )

                )
```

I want the "object" array that has the "Others" subcat, to be placed at the end of it's own array...how to do that ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: did you checked `array_push()`?

Comment: that's the problem, can't just use unset and array_push....what there it's a multilevel array, I just placed a small part of it as an example...regardless of the key of the object that has "Others" , how am I gonna put the object that has "Others" at the end of the array?

Comment: @sasori: Do you want to shift the position of every object containing  `Others` to the end, or just the first one?

Comment: exactly @AmalMurali, so how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your new edit, Try this,

```
           $temp = Array();
           foreach ($bigarray['result']['Business Services'] as $k=>$smallarr){


            if($smallarr['subcat'] == 'Others'){
                $temp = $bigarray['result']['Business Services'][$k];
                unset($bigarray['result']['Business Services'][$k]);
                $bigarray['result']['Business Services'][] = $temp;
            }
           }

           print_r($bigarray);
```

full demo with your array at http://codepad.org/vmwd24Tp

Comment: you specified the 'Business Services' inthe foreach, is there any other way to solve it without indicating the Business Services? ...because , there's a possibility that not only Business Services has the Others in one of it's object

Comment: yup you can add another for loop inside the first loop, the same way you did in your ans.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reindex the array, you can do something like this

```
$tempElement = $bigarray[0][2];
unset($bigarray[0][2]);

$bigarray[0] = array_values($bigarray[0]); // reindex array
$bigarray[0][] = $tempElement;
```

or with custom index range

```
$tempElement = $bigarray[0][2];
unset($bigarray[0][2]);

$bigarray[0] = array_combine(range(0, count($bigarray[0]) - 1), array_values($bigarray[0]));
$bigarray[0][] = $tempElement;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you’re looking for?

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "status" => "success",
    "total" => 17,
    "count" => 0,
    "start" => 0,
    "result" => array(
        "Business Services" => array(
            0 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 171,
                "subcat" => 12345,
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            1 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 22,
                "subcat" => "Business Opportunities",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            2 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 23,
                "subcat" => "Courier Services",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            3 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 24,
                "subcat" => "Databases",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            4 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 25,
                "subcat" => "Office Furniture & Equipment",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            5 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 26,
                "subcat" => "Other Business Services",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            6 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 27,
                "subcat" => "Printing & Copying",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            7 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 28,
                "subcat" => "Publications",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            8 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 29,
                "subcat" => "Security Products & Services",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                ),
            9 => array(
                "maincatid" => 3,
                "subcatid" => 30,
                "subcat" => "Translation Services",
                "maincat" => "Business Services"
                )
            ),
        "Courses" => array(
            0 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 45,
                "subcat" => "Academic Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            1 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 46,
                "subcat" => "Computer Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            2 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 47,
                "subcat" => "Cooking & Baking Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            3 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 48,
                "subcat" => "Dance Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            4 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 49,
                "subcat" => "Fitness & Gym Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            5 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 50,
                "subcat" => "Flower Arrangement Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            6 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 51,
                "subcat" => "Hair Dressing & Beauty Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            7 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 52,
                "subcat" => "Language Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            8 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 53,
                "subcat" => "Music Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            9 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 60,
                "subcat" => "Others",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            10 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 54,
                "subcat" => "Photography & Video Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            11 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 55,
                "subcat" => "Self Improvement Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            12 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 56,
                "subcat" => "Swimming Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            13 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 57,
                "subcat" => "Tuition",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            14 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 58,
                "subcat" => "Yoga & Pilates Lessons",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                ),
            15 => array(
                "maincatid" => 6,
                "subcatid" => 59,
                "subcat" => "Youth Programs & Courses",
                "maincat" => "Courses"
                )
            ),
        "Hobbies & Interests" => array(
            0 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 88,
                "subcat" => "Action Figures & Collectibles",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            1 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 89,
                "subcat" => "Antiques & Collectibles",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            2 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 91,
                "subcat" => "Books & Magazines",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            3 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 92,
                "subcat" => "Building Toys",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            4 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 94,
                "subcat" => "Club Memberships",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            5 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 95,
                "subcat" => "Comics & Manga",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            6 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 96,
                "subcat" => "Computer & Console Games",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            7 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 97,
                "subcat" => "Florist",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            8 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 98,
                "subcat" => "Gift Ideas",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            9 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 99,
                "subcat" => "Musical Instruments",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            10 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 104,
                "subcat" => "Others",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                ),
            11 => array(
                "maincatid" => 11,
                "subcatid" => 101,
                "subcat" => "RC (Remote Control)",
                "maincat" => "Hobbies & Interests"
                )
            )
        )
    );

foreach($arr["result"] as &$bigarray){
    if(is_array($bigarray)){
    $finalarray = array();
        foreach($bigarray as $smallarray){
            if($smallarray["subcat"] == "Others"){
            $temp = $smallarray;
            }
            else{
            $finalarray[] = $smallarray;
            }
        }
        if(isset($temp)){
        $finalarray[] = $temp;
        }
    $bigarray = $finalarray;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```

See demo [here](http://codepad.org/OhmZM7cN).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all your answers Sir(s)...I have finally figured out myself how to do it.
one of the answers has given me the idea in order to solve it.. thank you.
here's my own solution

```
             $temp = '';
             foreach($bigarray['result'] as $k => $big){
                foreach($big as $key => $smallarr){
                    //echo $key . ' = ' . $smallarr['subcat']."<br/>";
                    if($smallarr['subcat'] == 'Others'){
                        //$temp = $big[$key];
                        $temp = $bigarray['result'][$k][$key];
                        unset($bigarray['result'][$k][$key]);
                        $bigarray['result'][$k][] = $temp;
                    } 
                }
             }

 echo "<pre>",print_r($bigarray),"</pre>";
```

Comment: and then to sort the key of each object, i used the ksort() function .. ksort($bigarray);

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it what you are looking for, Just give a try:

```
$array = $bigarray[2];  //store 3rd element to a variable
unset($bigarray[2]);   // removing 3rd element from array
array_push($array, $bigarray);  //again pushing it at the end
```

For more info on [array_push()](http://php.net/array_push) and [unset()](http://php.net/unset).

Comment: `bigarray` and no `$` also this will `unset`, he wants to pop the element out and want to push the same one at the end

Comment: @Mr.Alien: thanks for correcting me. And yes it will unset the

Comment: I modified my example, so that you can see, what I meant,because I want it's possible that's there are one or more object that has "Others'

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand exactly what you want, if you want. you can try this.

```
$bigarray = array(
                0 => Array
                    (
                        'maincatid' => 3,
                        'subcatid' => 171,
                        'subcat' => 'asdfasdf',
                        'maincat' => 'Business Services'
                    ),

                1 => Array
                    (
                        'maincatid' => 3,
                        'subcatid' => 22,
                        'subcat' => 'Business Opportunities',
                        'maincat' => 'Business Services'
                    ),

                2 => Array
                    (
                        'maincatid' => 3,
                        'subcatid' => 23,
                        'subcat' => 'Others',
                        'maincat' => 'Business Services'
                    ),

                3 => Array
                    (
                        'maincatid' => 3,
                        'subcatid' => 24,
                        'subcat' => 'Databases',
                        'maincat' => 'Business Services'
                    )
           );

$resultArray = array();
$lastArray = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($bigarray);$i++){
    if ($bigarray[$i]['subcat']=='Others'){
        $lastArray[] = $bigarray[$i];
    }else{
        $resultArray[] = $bigarray[$i]; 
    }
}
print_r (array_merge( $resultArray , $lastArray));
```

Comment: I want to shift the position of every object containing Others to the end

Comment: The answer I posted will shift every array with `'subcat' => 'Others'` to the end.